# Pub Install keeps saying it has failed on all my projects after updating?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

Hey it looks to be more of a Dart issue but just to be sure,

```
name: CursorDiscoClient
description: Cursor Disco Time!
dependencies:
 browser: any
```

Is what my `pubspec.yaml` file looks like. The error I get is:

> Pub update failed, [3]

When I run `pub --trace install` I get the following:

```
vm\snapshot.cc:334: error: unreachable code
```

I am on Windows 8, Dart Editor version 24275. Is this something I am doing wrong?

My full code can be seen here: https://github.com/Plornt/CursorDiscoClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling Dart Editor.